# Accessing private field in Java class from another class

Tags: java, private-members

Hi all someone can explain why the last line at this code is legal:

```
public class HashCodeTest {
    private String value = null;

    HashCodeTest(String value) {
    this.value = value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<HashCodeTest, String> aMap = new HashMap<HashCodeTest, String>();
    aMap.put(new HashCodeTest("test"), "test");
    aMap.put(new HashCodeTest("test"), "test");
    System.out.println(aMap.size());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
    int result = 17;
    return 31 * result + value.hashCode();
    }

    public boolean equals(HashCodeTest test) {
    if (this == test) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!(test instanceof HashCodeTest)) {
        return false;
    }
    return test.value.equals(value);
    }
}
```

At the last line there is access to private field of test class but this is illegal.

Thanks,
Maxim

Answer (score 4):

Private fields are accessible by all instances of this class.

Answer (score 4):

Because it is an instance of the same class you are using it in.

Answer (score 4):

`value` is not a private variable of another *class*; it is a private variable of another *instance* of the same class. Therefore the access is completely legal.

Answer (score 0):

Access modifiers define access for a type, not the instance of a type.